# Heroku H10 error on Laravel app

Tags: laravel, heroku

I have a Laravel (v4.2.x)(OctoberCMS) App working on my localhost but when I send it to Heroku, the error code below happens:

```
Dec 23 01:22:49 abass heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=abass.herokuapp.com request_id=10537615-d95f-4ec8-a728-7fda1e18dee8 fwd="IPADDRESS" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
Dec 23 01:22:49 abass heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/humans.txt" host=abass.herokuapp.com request_id=0c521c63-bee9-4288-bd70-e7bb73c02621 fwd="IPADDRESS" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
Dec 23 01:22:50 abass heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=abass.herokuapp.com request_id=0af7376e-86ed-4302-ac2f-7199804810c6 fwd="IPADDRESS" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I just can't figure out what the problem is. The errors aren't descriptive enough, anyone else experience this problem and find a fix for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procfile was not directing to the correct location of index.php

Comment: How is your Procfile configured? I am having this error

Comment: Me too, if you could just share that information please

Answer (score 0):

this is what procfile must be:
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32217636)